# How to have only crystal report runtime installed on a client and to make it work?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a WPF app that uses SAP crystal reports.
When I transfer my app to the client machine, I install the crystal report runtime, but it doesn't work, my app crashes.

I get this error:

> Problem signature:
>
> Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
>
> Problem Signature 01:   manager.exe
>
> Problem Signature 02:   1.0.0.0
>
> Problem Signature 03:   5a674988
>
> Problem Signature 04:   PresentationFramework
>
> Problem Signature 05:   4.0.30319.17929
>
> Problem Signature 06:   4ffa7956
>
> Problem Signature 07:   7fc6
>
> Problem Signature 08:   ee
>
> Problem Signature 09:   System.Windows.Markup.XamlParse
>
> OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
>
> Locale ID:  9242
>
> Additional Information 1:   0a9e
>
> Additional Information 2:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
>
> Additional Information 3:   0a9e
>
> Additional Information 4:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

When I install the whole package(runtime and crystal report for visual studio) it works just fine. But those two installs take a lot of space.

I am using crystal report service pack 21 from this url:

https://www.tektutorialshub.com/how-to-download-and-install-crystal-report-runtime/

Isn't there a way to only have the runtime version and to make it work?

Also, the client machine is  64 bit and I have tried with the the 32bit version also, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.

I needed to install runtime 32bit AND runtime 64bit.

Also, I needed to install Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3 RC.

Now it works fine!

Comment: You might be able to get around needing both runtime versions.  Usually the need for both is because the project has a Target CPU value of Any.  If you change the Target CPU to only work for one or the other (x86 or x64) then you should only need the runtime specific to the targeted cpu type.  There probably isn't any need to change it now since you got it working, but I wanted to share this for future reference in case you were not aware.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot!